# Google API for Restaurants Places in specific country?

Tags: google-places-api

I want to get all restaurants in Cairo.
The API just getting 250 restaurant and I want all the restaurants.
I use the radius and location in API.
please help me !!

Comment: Please provide more specifications and examples of what you are using and what you are getting.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurant&location=24.612139%2C46.490391&radius=50000&key=[api-key]&language=ar

Comment: this the URL I using to get the restaurants . I make a loop each step adding 100 m to the radius starting from 1000 m to reach 50000 m and this the maximum . this algorithm get 250 restaurant only and riyadh country have more than 23,000 restaurant ! how can i get them all.

Comment: Places API returns only prominent places according to Google criteria. No guarantee you can get all possible places. It is not designed this way and doesn't work as database search.

Comment: so what should i do to get all possible places in spasific city ?

Comment: @ahmedkaram there is no defined solution for this but you can try something like searching with restaurant category (Italian, Chinese..). this is the only solution as far as I know